# Autolayout: Scale font up

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios8

I'm preparing my app for a bigger phone that takes full advantage of a bigger screen. We all know the feature that the font is scaled down until the content fits into the given label frame.

But how do I get the font size scaled up if autolayout enlarges my labels frame?